# firebase_storage/unauthenticated User is unauthenticated. Authenticate and try again error even in the release build

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, firebase-app-check

I'm using [`firebase_storage`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage) and [`firebase_app_check`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_app_check). I get the error in the following code.

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: 'foo@bar.com', password: '********');
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('images/foo.png').putFile(file)
```

> [firebase_storage/unauthenticated] User is unauthenticated. Authenticate and try again.

I've added the debug secret token to the console and the debug version of the app works fine, however, if I run the release version of the app on a physical Android device I get the error. Why is that so?

#### AppCheck Settings:

[image]

#### Project Settings

I've uploaded both debug and release certificates on the Firebase Project Settings page.

[image]

Comment: have you added secret token for release version to firebase console ?

Comment: i am asking about key hash :  https://pasteboard.co/eOYfLCoeDmnI.png  
this one

Comment: Have you keep both SH1, means debug and release one for that app or package name ?

Comment: but with the release one is debug one also there on  firebase console ?

Comment: @HardikMehta Yes, I have both debug and release certificates of both `SHA-1` and `SHA-256` on the console. Please see the updated post, it has a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more time thanks to the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers#initialize) for not providing enough information.

For release mode, in my `build.gradle(app)`:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0-beta04'
```

I also need to add in my `MainActivity.java`:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do one thing after adding `SHA-1`  and `SHA-256` for release build
Re download the `google-services.json` file and replace it with existing one in your project then do `flutter clean` and try to run release build and check.

Comment: I was able to make it work, check my answer.